# Is there any bit-stream extractor in scalable HEVC?

Tags: scalability, hevc, scalable, h.265

I'm using Scalable HEVC reference software (`SHM 12.2`).

I encode a video in two layers using the following script:

```
/home/Experiments/Zinon/SHM-12.2/bin/TAppEncoderStatic -c
cfg/encoder_randomaccess_scalable.cfg -c cfg/per-sequence-svc/C_L-1.5x.cfg 
-c cfg/layers.cfg -b str/C_L.bin -o0 rec/C_L_l0_rec.yuv -o1 rec/C_L_l1_rec.yuv
```

In scalable H.264, using Bit-stream extractor `“BitStreamExtractorStatic”` I can extract sub-streams of an AVC or SVC stream.

Do you know if there is a similar Bit-stream extractor in Scalable HEVC? Because in `SHM` there is no any.

In `SHM/source/App/utils/ExtractAddLS/` there is a text files that contains the following text. In any case I can't find an executable file of the `ExtractAddLS`, only a c-file.

This a tool that either:

1. Extracts an independent non-base layer from a multi-layer bitstream, converts it to a base-layer bistream and writes it to a file. The extraction processs is defined in chapter F.10.2 of the HEVC version 2 specification.

or

2. Extracts an additional layer set sub-bitstream from multi-layer bitstream and writes it to a file. The extraction processs is defined in chapter F.10.3 of the HEVC version 2 specification.

The tool is invoked as follows:

`ExtractAddLS <infile> <outfile> <Max temporal ID> <layer IDs of the extracted layers>`

The process that is invoked is decided based on the number of IDs that are given in the layer ID list.  If only one layer ID is given, independent non-base layer rewriting process is invoked. If more than one layer ID is given, sub-bitstream extraction for additional layer sets is invoked.

The result of independent non-base layer rewriting process can be decoded with an HEVC/H.265 v1 compliant decoder as long as the extracted independent layer conform with v1 specification text. The tool removes VPS from the output bitstream during rewriting so an HEVC/H.265 decoder should not expect it to be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of searching, I realized that the `SHM` decoder can extract the requested layer by just adding a parameter. For example:

```
TAppDecoderStatic -b str/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P.bin -olsidx 0 -o0 /yuv/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_0_dec.yuv >> /txt/pirkagia_10b_lowdelay_P_level_0_dec.txt
```

Using the parameter `-olsidx` we can select Index of output layer set to be decoded.